# Toggling value 1 and 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to send a value from js, if a button is clicked (for first time) send a value "1" to php file and again if it is clicked send a value "0" to the php file.

I am trying to do this way but it always alerts 0. Any help ?

```
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="countMe()">hello</a>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function countMe() 
{
 var isClicked;
 var x = (isClicked=="0") ? "1" : "0"; 
 alert(x);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code never changes `isClicked`, but even if it did it's a local variable. Those are your problems.

Comment: rethink... I mean do you see any logic in this?
isCLicked will always have the same value...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var isClicked = false;
function countMe() {
    isClicked = !isClicked;
    alert(isClicked ? '1' : '0');
}
```

Comment: You can shorten this if you're code golfing - alert((isClicked = !isClicked) ? '1' : '0'));

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning anything to isClicked. Try:

```
var isClicked = "0";
```

or any other assignment to gain a meaningful comparison.

Comment: Yes, it was just a demonstration to explain that the value of isClicked was never assigned to anything. @deceze's answer above is complete. In it, he initializes the isClicked variable, and toggles the value of isClicked every time someone clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid unnecessary global flags with a closure:

```
function makeToggler() {
    var isClicked = false;
    return function() {
        isClicked = !isClicked;
        return isClicked ? "1" : "0";
    }
}

var countMe = makeToggler();
```

The `countMe` function maintains its own state. Demonstration:

```
console.log(countMe());
console.log(countMe());
console.log(countMe());
console.log(countMe());
```

Output:

```
1
0
1
0
```

As an added benefit, the `makeToggler` function can be used to create additional counters, each of which would require their own (confusing) global variable in the standard solution.